# "_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte" after truncating a csv log file that is being piped to by another process

Tags: python, csv, pipe

How do I truncate a csv log file that is being used as std out pipe destination from another process without generating a `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte` error?

I have one process running `rtlamr > log/readings.txt` that is piping radio signal data to `readings.txt`. I don't think it matters what is piping to the file--any long-running pipe process will do.

I have a file watcher using `watchdog` (Python file watcher) on that file, which triggers a function when the file is changed. The function read the files and updates a database.

Then I try to truncate `readings.txt` so that it doesn't grow infinitely (or back it up).

```
file = open(dir_path+'/log/readings.txt', "w")
file.truncate()
file.close()
```

This corrupts `readings.txt` and generates the error (the start of the file contains garbage characters).

I tried moving the file instead of truncating it, in the hopes that `rtlamr` will recreate a fresh file, but that only has the effect of stopping the pipe.

EDIT
I noticed that the charset changes from `us-ascii` to `binary` but attempting to   truncate the file  with `file = open(dir_path+'/log/readings.log', "w",encoding="us-ascii")` does not do anything.

Comment: What's the `watchdog` that you are referring to? Doesn't look like https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog

Comment: From which end does the code that you gave run? Is the file still open by the other process at this moment?

Comment: It's https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/  The code I gave runs when the watchdog triggers an event that the `readings.txt` has changed by `rtlamr`.`rtlamr` is a black box utility that appends an update every 3 seconds. I don't know much about the underlying pipe file management behavior.

Comment: Do you really need the data to be persistently stored? A FIFO file (or some other implementation of a buffered pipe) looks like a better fit.

Comment: I don't need the data to be stored in the log file--but I do need to persist it in a database and writing to log file using a pipe is the only way I can get data out of out rtlamr. I am a newbie and kinda making it up as I go along and don't know the better patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you `truncate` a file<sup>1</sup> while another process has it open in `w` mode, that process will continue to write to the same offsets, making the file sparse. Low offsets will thus be read as `0`s.**

As per [x11 - Concurrent writing to a log file from many processes - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346062/concurrent-writing-to-a-log-file-from-many-processes) and [Can two Unix processes simultaneous write to different positions in a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667739/can-two-unix-processes-simultaneous-write-to-different-positions-in-a-single-file), each process that has a file open has its own offset in it, and a `ftruncate()` doesn't change that.

**If you want the other process to react to truncation, it needs to have it open in `a` mode.**

---

Your approach has principal bugs, too. E.g. it's not atomic: you may (=will, eventually) truncate the file after the producer has added data but before you have read it so it would get lost.

Consider using dedicated data buffering utilities instead like `buffer` or `pv` as per [Add a big buffer to a pipe between two commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554568/add-a-big-buffer-to-a-pipe-between-two-commands).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Which is superfluous because `open(mode='w')` already does that. Either `truncate` or reopen, no need to do both.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, man. You saved me hours of headaches witih this!